# pass data back to facebook app after authorisation

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, express

I am authotizing my app in the following way:

```
// authorize app!
                $('#authApp').click(function(){
                    var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
                    oauth_url += '?client_id=#{app.id}';
                    oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com/pages/null/#{fbPageId()}/?sk=app_#{app.id}');
                    oauth_url += '&scope=user_likes,user_photos';
                    oauth_url += '&app_data=7B%27game%27%3A+%27key%27%7D';
                    oauth_url += '&state=sbSbsbSb';
```

As you can see I am setting the 'state' param as part of the query string.
Now when the user authorizes the app he is redirected to the redirect url.

However the data passed in the state parameter is not posted to my app nor is it part of my app's iframe query string. I was expecting to find it as part of the signed request, but no. This is the deserialized signed request posted back after authorisation

```
{ algorithm: 'HMAC-SHA256',
  expires: 1348927200,
  issued_at: 1348921162,
  oauth_token: 'AAA...',
  page: { id: '490...', liked: true, admin: false },
  user: { country: 'ec', locale: 'en_US', age: { min: 21 } },
  user_id: '1...' }
```

I do see that the state is included of the parent page's query string. I need to access that parameter from my app (running inside an iframe). I believe that I cannot just access the parent page's window location because of same origin policy restrictions.

I have read through the documentation and searched online. Persisting data across an app authotization needs to be done using the state parameter. However it is nowhere stated how to retrieve that state param once redirected back to your app.

This is from the [facebook doc's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) regarding the state param:

> A unique string used to maintain application state between the request
>   and callback. When Facebook redirects the user back to your
>   redirect_uri, this parameter's value will be included in the response.
>   You should use this to protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery.

Am I supposed to get the state data back from the parent's page query string?
Or am I doing something wrong?

* EDIT ***
I am storing the user to user request Id in the state parameter. For example A invites B to participate in the app via a facebook request. Once B authorises the app A needs to be rewarded. So I need to know that B came to the app following A's invitation. Therefore I store the requestId in the state param, so once B has authorised the app I can take appropriate action.

*** EDIT 2 (SOLUTION) ****
If your redirect_uri is pointing to the Page Tab URL then facebook will NOT send back the state parameter! It will only be sent back if you redirect to the Canvas URL !!!!!

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook documentation you referenced is a bit confusing.  The only thing you should be doing with the state parameter is making sure you are not a victim of CSRF.  [Facebook's server side authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) gives an example of this in PHP.  In short, you should be storing the state value in the session and then verifying that the session value is the same as what Facebook passes back to you in the request.  The key line in their PHP example is:

```
if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
   // Continue with application logic here because state matches.
   // Otherwise, exit immediately because you're a victim of CSRF!
```

So back to your problem.  From your redirect URL and the response you are getting, it's obvious your app is on a Facebook Page Tab.  See the [authentication flow for page tabs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/) for how you should be doing this.  Note they are not using the state parameter in step 2 and that the state parameter is never mentioned in page tab authentication flow.  So even if you wanted to use the state parameter for something other than its intended use, you are out of luck.

Based on your edits, I suggest you check out the [documentation on requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/). Note that the user clicking on the request will be redirected to your **canvas** app, not the page tab.  "The canvas URL will also contain an additional GET parameter request_ids, which is a comma delimited list delimited list of Request IDs that a user is trying to act upon."  So there is no need for you to be trying to do this yourself.

Comment: I spent literally hours on this. Based on your response I changed the redirect_uri to the canvas url instead of the tab url and voila, the state parameter is sent back as part of the query string!!!!
For whatever reason, facebook is not sending the state parameter back when redirecting to a tab url.

Comment: that is exactly how I am proceeding in regards to the request_ids. However once the user clicks on the request and lands on my canvas page, he has not yet authorized the app, so I don't have permissions to delete the request just yet. Therefore I must wait until he has authorized the app. That is why I send the request_ids as the state param to the auth url.
Anyhow, all seems to working now. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

> Am I supposed to get the state data back from the parent's page query string?

No, not when authenticating within a canvas/page tab app. The only query string parameter that gets passed to your app in this scenario is the content of the `app_data` parameter.

But you don’t need the `state` parameter in this scenario – verifying the `signed_request` is absolutely sufficient, because it’s signed with your app secret, that only you and Facebook know. So that is enough protection against “manipulated” requests right there already.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas/ resp. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pagetab/ for more details. (And see how they do not mention the `state` parameter at all.)

Edit:

> I am storing the user to user request Id in the state parameter. For example A invites B to participate in the app via a facebook request. Once B authorises the app A needs to be rewarded. So I need to know that B came to the app following A's invitation. Therefore I store the requestId in the state param, so once B has authorised the app I can take appropriate action.

That’s a misuse of the `state` parameter … it’s supposed to achieve something completely different (CSRF protection, as the docs say).

While this *might work* in your scenario – why are you not using the `app_data` parameter to transmit this piece of information? That’s the *designated* way of transferring info to canvas/page tab apps.

Comment: look at the edit in the question. It explains the need for the state param. What I am storing there is actually the user to user request ID.

Comment: Apart from there being no actual visible _edit_ to your question, I guess you are referring to the quote from the Oauth dialog docs. As I said before, and Todd said again – there is _no need_ for this kind of protection in this scenario, because the `signed_request` already provides the necessary level of security here – there is no (realistic) way of faking it’s signature for a request that is not genuine.

Comment: wow that was fast! You must have visited while I was still editing the question. I did reply to you before editing, which I did immediately after replying to you.

Comment: I need to delete the request_ids. But since the user has not authorized the app yet, I do not have the necessary permissions to delete them when the user lands on my canvas page. Therefore I use the state parameter to have access to the request_ids after the user has authorized my app and I can finally delete them.

Comment: _“I need to delete the request_ids”_ – you don’t need a _user_ access token for that, you can use your _app_ access token as well.

Comment: I will try that out. If that works I can simplify a lot. I thought I required a user access token for that. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried out using the app access token and it works indeed. That allows me to simplify my flow tremendously. THANK YOU!